# How to change extension of a file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to change extension of a file with T-SQL? Just like the C# method `Path.ChangeExtension`?

For example I may have a file named `test1.csv` and I want to change it `test1.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [SQLMag article](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/rename-files-or-directories-fly-t-sql-scripts), there is a procedure named `sp_ReplaceFileOrDirNames` they made which can do what you want.

Their code uses [`xp_cmdShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) which allows you to call operating system commands. (You could call `xp_cmdShell` directly with `move` too if you don't want all this code.)

Their [code](http://sqlmag.com/site-files/sqlmag.com/files/archive/sqlmag.com/content/content/49567/listing_01.txt):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ReplaceFileOrDirNames 
  (@pathToObject varchar(200),
   @oldName      varchar(50),
   @newName      varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @winCmd           varchar(400)
  DECLARE @isFileThere      bit
  DECLARE @isDirectory      bit
  DECLARE @parentDirExists  bit
  DECLARE @fullNamewithPath varchar(250)
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET @fullNamewithPath = @pathToObject+'\'+@oldName 
      CREATE TABLE #temp (isFileThere     bit,
                          isDirectory     bit,
                          parentDirExists bit)
    INSERT #temp exec master..xp_fileExist @fullNamewithPath
      SELECT @isFileThere = isFileThere,
             @isDirectory = isDirectory 
      FROM #temp
      IF (@isFileThere = 1)
        BEGIN 
          SET @winCmd = 'rename ' + 
            @pathToObject+'\'+@oldName + ' ' + @newName
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
          IF (@isDirectory = 1)
            BEGIN 
              SET @winCmd = 'move /Y ' + @pathToObject+ '\' + 
                @oldName + ' '+ @pathToObject+'\'+@newName
            END
        END
      PRINT @winCmd
      EXEC master..xp_cmdShell @winCmd
      DROP TABLE #temp
      SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

Their code sample:

```
-- Rename a file called my Text.txt to test.txt in C:\appl\mssql.
exec sp_ReplaceFileOrDirNames @pathToObject= 'c:\appl\mssql',
                              @oldName='myText.txt',
                              @newName='test.Txt'
```